# Wi-Fi doesn't work well , disconnect (but connected) every 10 minutes

Tags: wireless, networking

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (with all drivers updated).

I'm connected to my wireless router, everything works well, but after 10 minutes using Firefox / Chrome / Skype / transmission  the connection is lost only on Ubuntu.  Other devices still have a connection to the Internet.

Ubuntu is still connected to the router but no access to internet, even the router address is not accessible.

I have to  disconnect and connect the Wi-Fi to establish a new connection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Internet connection randomly dropping?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147339/why-is-my-internet-connection-randomly-dropping)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the drivers for your wireless in the 'additional drivers' section of your system settings? Often these problems occur because of incompatible or faulty drivers.

It may help others to answer your question if you specify:

- Are you using a laptop? What is the make and model?
- What wireless hardware and drivers are you using?

Although it is a discontinued support program you should take a look at some of the documentation on the ubuntu wiki that can help diagnose and guide you through any hardware compatibility issues:

[Does Ubuntu Support the hardware configuration on your Laptop?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops?action=show&redirect=HardwareSupportMachinesLaptops)

[Is your wireless card supported?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)

It may be easier to just surf through the [Ubuntu Friendly](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/) site.

Sometimes the network struggles with WPA. User Erik Dietrich has a possible solution:

[Laptop Wifi problems](https://askubuntu.com/a/99026/75293)

Tell me if any of this works.

Answer (score 0):

At my laptop I have the same. I think this is bag of network-manager because I connect to my Wi-Fi though terminal and it works ok.

If you want to connect through terminal do this: 1. Install dhcpcd `sudo apt-get install dhcpcd`. 2. `sudo ifconfig` and find out your wireless card.(usually it wlan0 or eth2) 3. Find what networks are available `sudo iwlist <wireless card> scan`. 4. Choose your network `sudo iwconfig <wireless card> essid <wireless network name>`. 5. Connect to network `sudo dhcpcd -d -t 10 <wireless card>`.

Comment: i used this process  but probel still there

Comment: there could be 2 other things that could call the problem: bad drivers(try to reinstall it or install windows drivers with ndiswrapper) or some script turn wifi card off(check it ifconfig). You should try to ping some device when no internet also you should see your /etc/resolv.conf(maybe some program change dns).

Comment: yes i  can ping devices, router but still no internet

Comment: what about dns(/etc/resolv.conf). are they the same when internet is and when it's gone?

Answer (score 0):

Every time I setup Ubuntu (any version) on my Dell Precision M2400 I have to fix the same problem. For me it's a power management issue and I've bookmarked this guide to fix it http://uselessuseofcat.com/?p=67

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

As Erik mentioned in his post([Laptop Wifi problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99025/laptop-wifi-problems/99026#99026)), it is better to remove ubuntu default network-manager and use Wicd network manager... I had same problem and now it solved.

Erik suggestion:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall wicd
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
sudo service wicd restart
```

Comment: i tried to use Wicd, but problem still there